Corrupted GUID for External SSD
So, I have an External SSD of 2TB. I was unable to mount it after removing it accidentally from my laptop, without ejecting it. Then, I for some reason tried running the command:
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk4s2 --settype "Apple_HFS"

For my external hard disk. It is actually of ExFAT type, but after that it started showing Apple_HFS type, since I knew it was of type ExFAT I then ran:
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk4s2 --settype "ExFAT"

While, both commands ended in some failure. Now on running diskutil list I get this:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         494.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +494.4 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            20.5 GB    disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 20.5 GB    disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 12.2 GB    disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.9 GB     disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    380.9 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      24.6 KB    disk3s6

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +4.0 GB     disk5
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk6         4.0 GB     disk5s1

/dev/disk6 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.0 GB     disk6
                                 Physical Store disk5s1
   1:                APFS Volume AppleTVOS 16.4 Simul... 3.6 GB     disk6s1

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +4.2 GB     disk7
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk8         4.2 GB     disk7s1

/dev/disk8 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.2 GB     disk8
                                 Physical Store disk7s1
   1:                APFS Volume WatchOS 9.4 Simulator   3.9 GB     disk8s1

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +268.5 MB   disk9
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk9s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS DiskDrill               268.4 MB   disk9s2

/dev/disk10 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk10
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk10s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               2.0 TB     disk10s2

Here below, disk10s2 is now my drive. And it is showing completely stuck.
Using DMDE I was able find that my drive looks to be still there.
Can anyone help !!?


Welcome to Ask Different.  Great details. For you help, what does success look like specifically for your disk 4? Those seem odd commands to “try for some reason” - are you in the middle of testing if you can restore a backup?

Download and install GPT fdisk. Next, enter the following command. Here I assume the external drive is still /dev/disk10.
sudo gdisk /dev/disk10

The gdisk command is interactive. Enter the following.
t
2
700
w
y

